# Socket Programming C [Sending message to selected client]

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I have been trying to make a socket program in C. My aim was trying to do multi threaded server-client message app. So i could connect multi client to server and message them from server.

My code working but not as i want. For example if i run server and just one client, it send message to client its okay but when i try to connect another client, it sends messages part by part. For example if i write something in server and send, it goes first client; if i write something and send again, it goes second client. I need to choose which client i wanted to send the message but i couldn't figure it out. Could you help me please?

Here its server code

```
     #include <windows.h>
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <conio.h>
     #include <process.h>
     #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

     char buffer[100];

     int MyFunction(void* Arg)
      {
SOCKET Client = (*(int *)Arg);

while (1)
{   
    //int Socket = (*(int *)Arg);
    printf("-> ");
    gets(buffer);
    send(Client, buffer, 100, 0);   
}

_endthreadex(0);
    }
      /*--------------------------------------------------------------------            */
     void main(void)
     {
int a, b, c, d; 
int port;    
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
SOCKET Server;
SOCKET Client;
int clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);


// SOCKET  INITIALISATION
WSADATA WsaDat;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &WsaDat) != 0)
{
    printf("\n\n WSA Initialization failed!");
    exit(1);
}


// SOCKET
Server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (Server == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("\n\n Socket creation failed!");
    exit(1);
}
else
    printf("\n\n SOCKET IS CREATED SUCCESSFULLY...");


// SERVER  ADDRESS  
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
printf("\n ENTER THE SERVER IP ");
scanf_s("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
serv_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 = a;
serv_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2 = b;
serv_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3 = c;
serv_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4 = d;
printf("\n ENTER THE PORT NO ");
scanf_s("%d", &port);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);


// BIND 
if (bind(Server, (struct sockaddr *)(&serv_addr), sizeof(serv_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("\n\n Attempt to bind failed!STOP!!!");
}
else
    printf("\n\n BIND PROCESS IS CREATED SUCCESSFULLY...\n ");


// LISTEN 
if (listen(Server, 5) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    printf("\n Error in Listenning The Socket!\n");

/*---------------------------------------------------*/

int i = 0;
while (1)
{
        printf("\n SERVER IS RUNNING...\n ");

            printf("Client %d is connected!\n", i);



        Client = accept(Server, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &clilen);

        _beginthread(MyFunction, 0, (void *)&Client);

        i++;
}
_getch();


   }
```

And here is the client code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h> 
    #include<winsock2.h>
    #include<process.h>
    #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")


    char buffer[100];

    void MyFunction(void * Arg)
        {
SOCKET Socket = (*(int *)Arg);
while (1)
{

    recv(Socket, buffer, 100, 0);
    printf("Server: %s\n", buffer);
}
_endthread();
    }

    void main(void)
     {
WSADATA WsaDat;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WsaDat) != 0)
{
    printf("\n WSA Initialization failed.");
    exit(1);
}

struct STRUCTADDR
{
    short  sin_family;
    short  sin_port;
    struct in_addr sin_addr;
    char   sin_zero[8];
};

struct STRUCTADDR p1_addr, cli_addr;
int clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
p1_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
int a, b, c, d;
printf("\n\n ENTER THE SERVER IP ");
scanf_s("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
p1_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 = a;
p1_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2 = b;
p1_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3 = c;
p1_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4 = d;
int port;
printf("\n\n ENTER THE PORT NO ");
scanf_s("%d", &port);
p1_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

/*--------------------------------------------*/

SOCKET Socket;
Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("\n Socket creation failed.");
    exit(1);
}
printf("\n SOCKET IS CREATED SUCCESSFULLY");
if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR *)(&p1_addr), sizeof(p1_addr)) != 0)
{
    printf("\n Failed to establish connection with server...");
}

else
    //while (1)
    //{
        printf("\n\n CONNECTED\n");
        _beginthread(MyFunction, 0, (void *)&Socket);

    //}
_getch();


    }
```

Comment: '_beginthread(MyFunction, 0, (void *)&Client);' no.  Passing the address of the same local var to all the threads is not safe.  'recv(Socket, buffer, 100, 0);' failure to correctly and completely handle the result returned by recv().  'printf("Server: %s\n", buffer);' calling 'printf("%s...' on a char array that is not guaranteed NUL-terminated.  Other stuff.

Comment: Why are you using threads? Nothing in what you've done so requires them and you can do a single threaded multiclient server using `select()`.

Comment: Also, don't use `gets` - it's no longer part of the C standard and very prone to buffer overruns.

Comment: Actually i have no idea what im doing. Im new at socket programming. Im just trying to do my aim. Of course bunch of these are maybe wrong or uneccessary

Comment: When i use **scanf_s("%s",buffer)** instead of **gets**, its not working

Answer (score 0):

When you accept socket in server, you need to add the accepted socket in a queue or an array rather than passing it directly to your thread function. Optionally you can also store the IP address of each peer as returned by accept() call, so that you can identify a given client when you want to send data to them

Comment: Is that good idea to take  all connected cli_addr value then i can use it in _beginthread(MyFunction, 0, (void *)&cli_addr); here. Actually i couldnt figure it out which one is taking the adress to send message.